# =="i" in python should match iteration's i not literal i, any way?

Tags: python, database, pandas, numpy, for-loop

I have a pandas dataframe (combined_csv) with Awayteam/Hometeam in two columns, and in the third column the winner name. The Team_Names is an array of the unqiue team names, and in order to fill up the win % dictionary for each team, i have to query the below condition in line 3. However, instead of matching with i the team name it matches with i, literally. Is there a workaround?

```
win_percentage={}
 for i in Team_Names:
     win_percentage[i]=combined_csv.query('AwayTeam=="i" or HomeTeam=="i"')['winner']
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the double-quotes around `i`?

Comment: you need to use `for i in range(len(Team_Names)`:

Comment: Use string formatting to substitute the value of `i` into the string.

Comment: @Adam No, that isn't the issue at all. OP does want the values that are contained in `Team_Names`, not the integer values. What you propose is poor style even in the cases where it does the right thing. Please read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - i will thanks for the comment. i misunderstood him. thats why i removed my answer

Comment: I haven't used `query`, but a quick read of its docs suggest that `'AwayTeam==@i'` might work, since `i` is a variable in the environment.

Comment: Maybe you could use an f-string: `f'AwayTeam=="{i}" or HomeTeam=="{i}"'`

Answer (score 0):

So you are creating a dictionary win_percentage.
I hope you have created the dataFrame combined_csv, then try this

```
`win_percentage={}
 for i,val in enumerate(Team_Names):
     a=combined_csv['AwayTeam'][i]
     b=combined_csv['HomeTeam'][i]
     c=combined_csv['winner'][i]
     if (a==val or b==val) and (c==a or c==b):
         win_percentage[i]=percentage_value`
```

with limited info to the problem,u need to calculate percentage_value some how